# correct answer tracker in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out how to add a score counter for the mini quiz that I made. I've tried different things and even tried to look up how to do it but I just cannot figure it out for what ever reason. Please help!

This is the code:

```
score = 0

def question1():
     print("1. Who hit the walk-off home run to extend the A's AL-record win streak to 20 games in 2002?"
              "A. Kevin Millar"
              "B. Scott Hatteberg"
              "C. Sammy Sosa"
              "D. Josh Donaldson")
     a = input("Please enter your answer in a lower case letter:")
     if a == 'C':
        print('You are smart!')
        score += 1 
     else:
        print('Better luck next time!') 
     return

def question2():
    print("2.   Who was the last Tigers pitcher to throw a no-hitter?")
    b = input("What is your final answer:")

    if b == 'Justin Verlander':
        print('I am impressed whith how smart you are')
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Are you even trying")  
    return 



def Quiz():
    question1()
    question2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `score` as global inside your functions.

```
def question2():
    # declare that you're using the global variable score
    global score
    print("2.   Who was the last Tigers pitcher to throw a no-hitter?")
    b = input("What is your final answer:")

    if b == 'Justin Verlander':
        print('I am impressed whith how smart you are')
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Are you even trying")  
    return
```

If you don't tell the interpreter that you're using the global variable, it assumes that you're referring to a `score` variable that was declared in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As Allie Filter [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309776/8617309), declaring `score` as global is one possibility. You can also take OOP inspired approach and create a `class Test` with `question` as a method and `score` as a class variable.

```
class Test:
    score = 0

    def question1(self):
        print("1. Who hit the walk-off home run to extend the A's AL-record win streak to 20 games in 2002?"
          "A. Kevin Millar"
          "B. Scott Hatteberg"
          "C. Sammy Sosa"
          "D. Josh Donaldson")
        a = input("Please enter your answer in a lower case letter:")
        if a == 'C':
            print('You are smart!')
            self.score += 1 
        else:
            print('Better luck next time!') 
        return True

    def question2(self):
    ...
    ...

    def take_quiz(self):
        self.question1()
        self.question2()
        return self.score
```

You can run your test by creating an instance of `Test` and calling method `take_quiz()` on it.

Some basics of OOP can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) and in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).